# Ethernet connection with discrete magnetics

Tags: raspberry-pi, ethernet, magnetics, cm4

I'm in the process of designing a carrier board for a raspberry pi cm4. Since I want to get everything as small as possible, I'm planning to use discrete magnetics for the ethernet connection. Looking at reference designs I came up with the following schematic.

[image]

For the signal transformer I'm using: WE-STST
https://www.we-online.com/catalog/en/WE-STST

For the line filter I'm using: WE-CNSW
https://www.we-online.com/catalog/en/WE-CNSW

Since I am an absolute newby when it comes to designing ethernet connections it would be great if someone with more experience could comment on this design and if it has any chances of being functional. Any input is greatly apreciated!

Comment: Since size is important, why not reduce the parts count by limiting to RX/TX only and removing the extra transformers and filters?

Comment: @icodeplenty what extra there is? Gigabit uses all 4 pairs.

Comment: @Chris, you are correct, I didn't notice the gigabit label and thought it was slower design.

Comment: Chris that can't work so it is copied wrong from any reference schematics or the reference schematics were wrong. Design review questions are dfficult as there might not be a single correct answer and you have not said much limitations. Why not simply use a small magjack for example, it is much smaller and easier than discrete magnetics. Please try fixing that with reference schematics.

Comment: @Justme A magjack unfortunately takes up to much vertical space. The design will be implemented in a existing device and must be as flat as possible. So im kind of stuck with discrete magnetics. Could you specify where you see errors?

Comment: R1,2,4,5 violate the galvanic isolation provided by the transformers. I’d be expecting a capacitor in there.

Comment: "A magjack unfortunately takes up too much vertical space"  Did you search for low profile magjack?  Those are longer instead of taller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

List of errors:

-Pull-ups of 10k on MCU side data pins make little sense. CM4 reference design has none.

-Pull-downs of 10k on cable side data pins make little sense. Ethernet is supposed to be an isolated interface. Uf this is supposed to be Bob Smith termination, resistor values are wrong and they should be AC terminated with caps. At least not connected to GND directly.

-Pinout of 8P8C connector is wrong. pins 3-4 are not a pair, nor 5-6.

Comment: Thank you for specifying! :)

Comment: Removing the pullups and fitting a proper bob smith termination on the connector side center taps resulted in a working design. Thanks for helping out!